# How to enable fiddler for dotnet core API

Tags: .net-core, fiddler

I am new to dotnet core 2 API, need to find a way to enable fiddler for this.

I do not find sufficient references online.  Looking for help from the community.

Comment: This should get you started:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-fiddler-with-asp-net-web-api-testing/

Comment: @j03p it's regarding donetcore2 service/api